# nginx rtmp compile for windows error U1052 & rtmp-module-master/config not found

Tags: c++, nginx, compiler-errors, makefile, nginx-location

I'm trying to follow this guide - http://www.helping-squad.com/nginx-rtmp-compile-for-windows/

To compile nginx rtmp for Windows, but when I'm trying to execute `nmake -f objs/Makefile`, it gives an error, namely - `NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'Makefile' not found` and the call prior to that gives an error as well.

**Code**

```
auto/configure --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=temp/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --sbin-path=nginx.exe --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=temp/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=temp/scgi_temp --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs/lib/pcre2-10.21 --with-zlib=objs/lib/zlib-1.2.8 --with-openssl=objs/lib/openssl-1.0.1s --with-select_module --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=objs/lib/nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

**Error** - `auto/configure: error: no objs/lib/nginx-rtmp-module-master/config was found`

Even there is a config file in the directory.

So I read something like - newer versions of nginx don't need a seperate rtmp-module-master so I removed that from the code & it compiled just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had placed the files / maps for the compiler in documents instead of -

`C:\msys\1.0\home\gr\nginx\objs\lib`

so the compiler couldn't find my files.